# Configuração manual de Spring Data

Tags: java, spring-data

Estou tentando usar o SpringData num projeto JFace/SWT.
Pois o recurso de auto implementação dos CrudRepository é algo fantástico e muito vantajoso.

Para isto, eu inclui aqui no classpath as coisas necessárias do SpringData: 
Spring Data Commons, Spring Data JPA, Spring Bean, Spring Context.

Para mim, seriam somente 4 passos pra fazer isso manualmente:

1 - Incluir os jars no classpath (não tenho erro de classpath)
2 - Anotar na aplicação as informações para o Spring sair cassandos as classes:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.wender.foobar")
public class ControleGadoApp extends ApplicationWindow {
```

3 - Criar uma interface que estenda o CrudRepository:

public interface ClienteRepository extends CrudRepository

4 - Criar um atributo de classe e anota-lo com @Autowired

```
public class TelaCliente extends AbstractTela {

    @Autowired
        private ClienteRepository repository;
```

Esses quatro passos não foram suficientes, o @Autowired não funcionou e a variável de classe está vindo nula.

**Há mais alguma configuração?**

Comment: Como você está instanciando o `TelaCliente`? Você precisa ter um container Spring que controle a injeção de dependências. Referência: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html

Comment: Eu descobri o problema, eu precisei inicializar minha aplicação como CommandLine Application (spring boot)

Comment: Beleza! Coloca o seu código aqui como resposta, para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que a aplicação não estava sendo inicializada como uma aplicação Spring. Pra mim isso não era necessário para aplicação desktop, era coisa de web application. Inclusive segue abaixo os dois detalhes (1) anotar @SpringBootApplication e (2) implementar CommandLineRunner

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App extends ApplicationWindow implements CommandLineRunner  {

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
   //Aqui eu coloquei o que antes estava no método main 
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}
```